# Run ImageMagick TextCleaner on batch files

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing

It is possible to use the TextCleaner script provided by Fred Weinhaus on batch files ?

I didn't find anything about this. I searched and for other scripts there are various methods but not for TextCleaner.
There is a "universal" command to run ?

I use Cygwin on Windows to execute the script.

I am also new to ImageMagick so I don't know too much..

This is the command I use:

```
textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 50 -o 10 -s 10 image_0in.png image_out.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My textcleaner script will only process one image at a time. You will have to write a script loop over each image you want to process and then call textcleaner for each image in the loop.

You can create a list manually of all images you want to process. Or if all your images are in one directory (and they have no spaces in the names), then you can do

```
cd to directory holding the images
list=`ls`
for img in $list; do
name=`convert $img -format "%t" info:`
textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 50 -o 10 -s 10 $img ${name}_out.png
done
```

or better (even if files have spaces in the names)

```
cd to directory holding the images
for img in *.png; do
name=`convert "$img" -format "%t" info:`
textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 50 -o 10 -s 10 "$img" "${name}_out.png"
done
```

Comment: You know if there is any chance that the script you posted can be executed from Python ?

Comment: You can create a python loop and then use python subprocess to call the bash shell script. See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=32920

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full Weinhaus script of course, but it does the basic image enhancement you are looking for:

*textcleaner.bat*

```
cd /d %~dp0

set filtersize=40
set offset=5

FOR %%i in (%1) do (
    del/q "%%~dpni.new3.png"
    echo Cleaning %1 ...
    "Z:\_grafik\imagick\bin\convert" -respect-parenthesis ^( "%1" -colorspace gray -set colorspace RGB -contrast-stretch 0 ^) ^( -clone 0 -negate -contrast-stretch 0 -lat %filtersize%x%filtersize%+%offset%%% ^) -compose Copy_Opacity -composite -fill white -opaque none +matte -deskew 50%% -alpha off "%%~dpni.new.png"
)
```

Usage:

```
textcleaner.bat myimage.png
---> will create myimage.new.png
```